# libGDX: Delay in ClickListener

Tags: java, libgdx, clicklistener

I want to change a button style when I'm clicking on this button. 
This is my solution:

```
show(){
   ...
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   stage.add(myButton); 
}

public void render(float delta){
   final boolean buttonSwitch;
   myButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            if(buttonSwitch == true)
            {
                  myButton.setStyle(style1);
            }
            else 
            {
                  myButton.setStyle(style2);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that sometimes my clicks will be ignored and the style will not be changed. I have to click three times or more to get a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding Listener in render method ?? why !!

Remove below code snippet from render method and keep in `show()` method

```
final boolean buttonSwitch;
myButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

             myButton.setStyle(buttonSwitch?style1:style2);
             buttonSwitch=!buttonSwitch;   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer ;))

Comment: With this solution I can only switch one time the button style. How can I solve this?

Comment: switching button style why ? what do you want to achieve ? and one more thing what is `if(x == true)` , x is float locally

Comment: This was just an example. The idea is that I change the button style to "buttonstyle1" and if i click again on this the button the button style will change to "buttonstyle2" and so on.

Comment: @EricM.I made an edit. Does (x == true) even compile? If so there might be your problem. I added a boolean that keeps track of the button state.

Comment: You don't even need the boolean. Just use button.isChecked()

Comment: @EricM. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44242038/3445320) answer

Comment: Thanks your answers! I've recognized that I have a problem with my ClickListener. 
When I'm doing: 
`myButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {  
           System.out.println("Click"); 
        }
    });`

It only runs two times and prints "Click".

Comment: @EricM. you should override `clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)`  method of  `ClickListener` instead of  `touchUp(..)`